# Javascript + Pretty Print JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin or a standalone script that will take a javascript object and create a navigatable tree like the FireBug plug in does.

Does this exist, or will I need to write one? Googling hasn't found much yet.

Comment: When you say "create a navigable tree" - do you mean with HTML/Javascript?  And if so - how? Inline on the page? Iframe? New window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.netgrow.com.au/files/javascript_dump.cfm